# how to build android apk in non-gui linux server

Tags: android, linux, build, android-sdk-tools

Want to set up a linux server only to build and test, and I found Android does not offer sdk only package anymore.

Previous  [sdk download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) was redirect to studio download page.

I need android sdk package. but now Android only supply the [sdk-tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads), in my mind sdk-tool/ is under sdk/, like path-to-sdk/tools. When android project builds, I need to set env `$ANDROID_HOME`, and `$ANDROID_HOME` is the directory of the sdk/ not the sdk/tool/

I try the android-studio-linux, but the pack I unzipped can not found android sdk, it seems android download sdk on first run.

I try the to find the android-sdk, but only get the [older releas](https://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html).

Please give me some suggestion, how to build android apk in non-gui linux server, the server is Ubuntu 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Well they still offer, they just have moved it to bottom to promote `Android Studio` more over other other IDEs.

Check the bottom of the [page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) or just use this [link](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip) to download it for linux. You can very well use gradle to build and package your app so if there is actually no compulsion of using `Android Studio`.

**Update** Also this [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html) explains how to develop `Android` apps/libs from commandline.

Comment: the [page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) provides the tools directory, but I want the sdk directory, the path is like this`sdk/tools/android`. When I build I have to  set `$ANDROID_HOME`, tools is one sub directory of the sdk directory